# Ruby getting the longest word of a sentence

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create method named `longest_word` that takes a sentence as an argument and The function will return the longest word of the sentence.

My code is:

```
def longest_word(str)
  words = str.split(' ')
  longest_str = []
  return longest_str.max
end
```

Comment: If it's a sentence, don't you need to strip punctuation to avoid biasing the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you want to split the string. If you are happy with using a single space, than this works:

```
def longest(source)
  arr = source.split(" ")
  arr.sort! { |a, b| b.length <=> a.length }
  arr[0]
end
```

Otherwise, use a regular expression to catch whitespace and puntuaction.

Comment: wow it worked thanks but can you explain me what the "<=>" are used for?

Comment: Oh that's a good way too. Would it be faster performance-wise?

Comment: sure. it's a comparison method, each class overrides it with class-specific implementations. In this case, it will use the Fixnum version (because it's called on a Fixnum object). [Check it here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-sort)

Comment: @CDub precisely, although it's a method, not a builtin operator.

Comment: @JustusDannyEapen I think it would not be slow, because `Array#sort!` and `Fixnum#<=>` are part of Ruby core and are implemented in plain C.

Answer (score 16):

The shortest way is to use Enumerable's `max_by`:

```
def longest(string)
  string.split(" ").max_by(&:length)
end
```

Comment: This might be the best answer, IMHO.

Comment: I agree. I guess `max_by` internally does a reduce/inject/fold like I used in my answer.

Comment: There's no one right way to do this problem, in my opinion.  All the answers given will solve the problem.  We're likely arguing over cycles which in today's world don't really matter. :)  But thanks for the upvotes guys. :)  Makes me feel good that late on a Sunday night I can still think clearly!

Comment: While there's not just one way to do it, people like to acknowledge an elegant solution.

Comment: For sure the other solutions are no better because there is no need to modify variables or doing to much code for just this simple problem. Your solution is smart and functional.

Comment: Yes, I think that for "one spot" tasks this kind of elegant one-liners are concise, clear and efficient (they leverage the low-level implementation of the interpreter). Honestly, I didn't know about `max_by` :-). Maybe my answer is more flexible in a scenario where you need a more custom sorting logic.

Answer (score 4):

Using regexp will allow you to take into consideration punctuation marks.

```
s = "lorem ipsum, loremmm ipsummm? loremm ipsumm...."
```

first longest word:

```
s.split(/[^\w]+/).max_by(&:length)
# => "loremmm"
# or using scan
s.scan(/\b\w+\b/).max_by(&:length)
# => "loremmm"
```

Also you may be interested in getting all longest words:

```
s.scan(/\b\w+\b/).group_by(&:length).sort.last.last
# => ["loremmm", "ipsummm"]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def longest_word(sentence)
  longest_word = ""
  words = sentence.split(" ")
  words.each do |word|
    longest_word = word unless word.length < longest_word.length
  end
  longest_word
end
```

That's a simple way to approach it. You could also strip the punctuation using a gsub method.

Answer (score 1):

Funcional Style Version

```
str.split(' ').reduce { |r, w| w.length > r.length ? w : r }
```

Another solution using max

```
str.split(' ').max { |a, b| a.length <=> b.length }
```

Answer (score 1):

`sort_by`! and `reverse`!

```rb
def longest_word(sentence)
  longw = sentence.split(" ")
  longw.sort_by!(&:length).reverse!
  p longw[0]
end

longest_word("once upon a time long ago a very longword")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want to do it in the Ruby way it would be:

```
def longest(sentence)

     sentence.split(' ').sort! { |a, b| b.length <=> a.length }[0]

end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is to strip the word from the extra chars

sen.gsub(/[^0-9a-z ]/i, '').split(" ").max_by(&:length)

Answer (score 0):

## Find Longest word in a string

```
sentence = "Hi, my name is Mesut. There is longestword here!"

def longest_word(string)
  long = ""
  string.split(" ").each do |sent|
    if sent.length >= long.length
      long = sent
    end
  end
  return long
end

p longest_word(sentence)
```