# Ruby Error with .length method

Tags: ruby

I am running into an error with my code and I am not sure why. I am trying to create a function that returns the longest word in a string. The only built-in Ruby method I can use is .split. My code is below and the error I receive is below that. Any help with figuring this out would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
def longest_word(sentence)
    sentence1 = sentence.split
    longest_word = ""

for i in 0...sentence1.length
    if i.length > longest_word.length 
        longest_word = i 
    end 
end 
return longest_word
end

longest_word("one three")
```

Error below:

```
undefined method `length' for 0:Fixnum
(repl):15:in `block in longest_word'
(repl):14:in `times'
(repl):14:in `longest_word'
(repl):29:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're iterating through the integers `0, 1, 2` when you pass `"one three"` as your argument.

Unfortunately, you can't call the `length` method directly on the integer/fixnum `i`. Instead, you want to call it on the element at the index `i` of the array `sentence1` if that makes sense.

Something like this should work for you:

```
def longest_word(sentence)
  sentence1 = sentence.split
  longest_word = ""

  for i in 0...(sentence1.length - 1)
    if sentence1[i].length > longest_word.length 
      longest_word = sentence1[i]
    end 
  end
  return longest_word
end
```

Or, better yet

```
def longest_word(sentence)
  sentence.split.max_by(&:length)
end
```

(Stolen from https://stackoverflow.com/a/21977468/716039)

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining this for me.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because `sentence.length` returns an array and you are doing `i.length` which is you are checking length of `Fixnum`.
Change your code to below:

```
def longest_word(sentence)
  sentence1 = sentence.split
  longest_word = ""

  sentence1.each do |word|
    longest_word = word if word.length > longest_word.length
  end 
  return longest_word
end

longest_word("one three")
```

Comment: No need for an explicit `return` and your indentation is mangled, but the use of `each` is a huge improvement.

Comment: you can also rewrite the 'if' statement into a one liner. `longest_word = word if word.length > longest_word.length`

Comment: Thank you for your help and information! I really appreciate it.